# Go struct parameter is empty after Gorm Create but the struct itself not

Tags: go, mariadb, grails-orm

I'm having a weird problem with GO/Gorm right now.

```golang
    request := model.IOSDeviceRequestLog{
        DeviceID:    deviceId,
        RequestType: requestType.String(),
    }

    log.Info("Creating request: ", request)

    if err := r.DB.Clauses(clause.Returning{}).
        Create(&request).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Info("Created request: ", request) // LOG 1
        log.Infof("Request ID: %s", request.RequestID) // LOG 2
```

```golang
type IOSDeviceRequestLog struct {
    RequestID   string       `gorm:"primary_key;default:UUID()" json:"requestId"`
    DeviceID    string       `json:"deviceId" gorm:"size:200;not null"`
    Device      IOSDevice    `json:"device" gorm:"constraint:OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    RequestType string       `json:"requestType" gorm:"not null;type:enum ('xxx', 'xxx');"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time    `gorm:"autoCreateTime" json:"createdAt"`
    HandledAt   sql.NullTime `json:"handledAt" gorm:"default:null"`
}
```

Im trying to create a new request of type `model.IOSDeviceRequestLog` and I expect, that after the `Create` function was executed without an error, that the request variable is filled with the default parameters like e.g. the `RequestID`.

Somehow the log after the create (LOG 1) returns:

```
Created request: { xxx_device_id_xxx { 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC  0 0 0 0} LECTURE_UPDATE_REQUEST 2023-01-31 16:50:40.729 +0000 UTC {0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC false}}
```

And the second log (LOG 2) returns:

```
Request ID:
```

So somehow the RequestID does not get returned.
The GORM Documentation states here (https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Returning-Data-From-Modified-Rows) that this should work for Databases that support the `returning` clause.
I'm using MariaDB which should support the `returning` clause (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/)

I've also tried to return the RequestID explicitly:

```golang
if err := r.DB.Clauses(clause.Returning{}).
        Create(&request).Error; err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

but this did not work too.

### Edit:

Okay somehowe Gorm does not include the returning clause in the final query. When running:

```golang
r.DB.Debug().Clauses(clause.Returning{
        Columns: []clause.Column{{Name: "request_id"}},
    }).Create(&request)
```

It just prints out:

```sql
INSERT INTO ios_device_request_logs (device_id,request_type,created_at) VALUES ('xxx_device_id_xxx','xxx','2023-01-31 17:47:27.956')
```

Comment: ummm... first thing i can think of... if I remember correctly, its not `gorm:"primary_key"` its `gorm:"primaryKey"`